# What is the interval of fragment-shader code execution?

Tags: glsl, performance, fragment-shader

Without any intended delay, is the code of a fragment-shader run once per frame? If not, how often will the code be executed? (I'm new to shaders: I'm talking about glsl if it makes any difference)

Comment: Yes it is. beacuse thats basicly why you have frames, beacuse you clear the screen every frame, so the gpu has to redraw every thing again.

Comment: "*is the code of a fragment-shader run once per frame?*" If you're asking this question, you probably need to find out what a [fragment shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader) *does* first. Once you understand that, it should be obvious how often it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you bind your program (2 shaders) with `useProgram` function, shaders are run at every `drawElements` or `drawArrays` call.

You can call those functions at every frame, 1000 times per frame, or once an hour.

You can also examine the "work at the server" during the single `drawElements` call. Vertex (or fragment) shader should be run for every vertex (or fragment). It is usually done on massively parallel hardware systems with many cores. Tens, hundreds or even thousands of instances of the shader program can run at the same time. And those systems are in our pockets! :)

Comment: The fragment shader is executed each time a fragment is generated :D

Comment: @gareththegeek - this is correct and you should make it an answer (expand a bit though) so it can get some proper +1s.

Comment: @mh01 Agreed -- the OP seems to be lacking some basic understanding of the pipeline. I think a brief explanation about how the different shaders relate to the pipeline would help.